# circular hour selector

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface

I would like to use a circular hour selector, like the following from [Oakland Crimespotting](http://oakland.crimespotting.org/#types=AA,Mu,Ro,SA,DP,Na,Al,Pr,Th,VT,Va,Bu,Ar&lat=37.806&hours=0-6,20,21&zoom=14&lon=-122.270&dtstart=2012-03-09T23:59:59-07:00&dtend=2012-03-16T23:59:59-07:00):

[image]

The user can effectively check or uncheck hours (or other time increments) around the circle.

Rather than implement this myself, can anyone point me to existing JS libraries or jQuery plugins?

Comment: I assume you've probably checked their source, but it is a flash object. Did a quick google search and it doesnt seem like this has been invented before, so it might be a useful plugin to make (and/or sell) too.

Comment: Yeah, I know that example is Flash-based.

FYI, I just found a circular month selector written with the d3 visualization library: http://windhistory.com/